# Wordpress cron job only when 'user visit website'?

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I've heard that the wordpress cron job only works when a trigger like 'user visits the website' occurs. What if I want to run a cron job every night automatically that runs a .php file. The complete scenario is that I want to save some data coming from a third party source as an API call to one of my custom php file, say savedata.php, and I save this data in a text file (for now) and another .php file say: executecron.php is ready to run automatically at 11 pm at night. How can I do this in wordpress without any users visiting my website? And I want to notify that I do not have permission to log into the dashboard but I can work all the php files.

Also please have patience with me as I'm totally new to wordpress development.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far, where **exactly** are you stuck? By googling for that topic, I find many tutorials immediately

Comment: I don't think that `wordpress cron jobs` are what you're after, take a look at `linux cron jobs`, (aka the `real cron jobs`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, WordPress Cron Job are only loaded once the user visit the site.

So, as of your problem you want to automatically load the file at certain interval of time you need to configure the cron job from the server and specify the path of the file you want to cron job at fixed interval of time.

The setting mostly found in the cPanel menu but it might vary according to the hosting provider or you can ask hosting provider support team for doing it.

Here are the useful links:

[Site Ground Real Cron Job](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/wordpress/real-cron-job/)

[Cron Job for WordPress](https://www.easycron.com/cron-job-tutorials/how-to-set-up-cron-job-for-wordpress)

If you still find issue please contact me for solving issue.